# How to Click OK on chrome popup using Selenium Webdriver C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to code below script for clicking OK button through script but fail to do it.

[image]

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

What am I doing wrong, Correct me.

Comment: URL please dear

Comment: what error u got?

Comment: Any reason you have removed the accepted answer for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an excellent nuget package, AutoItX.Dotnet, that will handle popups in chrome. 
Link to nuget package - https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoItX.Dotnet/

Please use the code below as a reference

```
//This code snippet will fix your specific issue
AutoItX.WinWait("Untitled - Google Chrome", "", 2);
AutoItX.WinActivate("Untitled - Google Chrome");
AutoItX.Send("{Enter}");

//Use code below to switch between buttons/text boxes within the popup
//And send text to text boxes within the popup
AutoItX.Send("{TAB}");
AutoItX.Send("HelloWorld");
```

You may have to test a bit further to see what keys you need to pass to make this code work seamlessly with each specific popup that you wish to interact with.

Comment: Thank you Brendan! I really appreciate for your help and this will get helpful for me in future scripts which I will be implementing.

Comment: AutoIt made your script dependent to microsoft windows. If you are going to run scripts on only microsoft only then it will fine for you

Comment: @ShubhamJain I agree with you 100%. Thanks for noting that for future readers.

Answer (score 1):

JavascriptExecutor should work for you. Just take care that you should execute it before clicking the event which invoke alert.

C# Code

```
IWebDriver driver; // assume assigned elsewhere
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
js.ExecuteScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Java Code

```
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }");
```

Note :- do not use it after clicking on event which invoke alert confirmation box. Above code by default set the confirmation box as true means you are accepting/click on ok on all confirmation box on that page if invoked

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Glad it work for you. Just take care that you are pressing on ok on each pop-up and the pop-up will not arise through out the session so check any pop-up in manaul navigation and see if you need to change the flag from true to false ie. ok to cancel :)